# How to change the body of the Http Response with ResponseBodyAdvice's beforeBodyWrite in order to change the encoding of the XML text to be returned?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, spring-restcontroller

How to decode response body to another encoding with `ResponseBodyAdvice`?

I have a @ControllerAdvice that just sets the header for the encoding, but doesn't touch the inside body. I need to decode it to another encoding:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = MyController.class)
    public class CharsetAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
        @Override
        public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
                                      Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                      ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
            HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
            headers.set("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=windows-1251");
            return body;
        }
    }
```

After applying the header, the content of the body is like `<tag field="РђР±РѕРЅРµРЅС‚ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅ"/>`, which looks like `UTF-8` bytes being decoded to `windows-1251` and then flushed to the HTTP response. But in fact, I need just my `UTF-8 String` with the same characters, but just in `windows-1251` encoding.

What I can to do with `Object` body in Java 8? How I can produce another body object with updated String?

What I should take from the `ResponseBodyAdvice`, the `request` or the `response` objects to get an updated body?